# Upgraded to wordpress 5.7 and now I can't select myself as a post author

Tags: block-editor, author

I started creating a new post and noticed on the right side where it says author, I can select any admin or editor but I can not select myself.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Could it be that you're already the author? Keep in mind this is a stack for WP developers, but this looks like a user support question better asked at wordpress.org. If that's not the case, please edit your question to include your code

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the issue you are facing is relating to your role?

If your role is set as `Author`, then by default you will be the selected author of the post and you are not able to select the author on creating a new post. Checking the WordPress Codex under ['Roles and Capabilities'](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/) shows that only roles with the capability of `edit_others_posts` can change the `Author` of the post.

You can find [this link to a table](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/#capability-vs-role-table) showing the roles and their related capabilities.

If this is not the issue you are having, please deactivate your plugins and set the theme to a default theme, such as ['Twenty Twenty One'](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentytwentyone/) and see if you are experiencing the same issue.